# MouseArea steals QQuickItem's mouse events

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

There's a `QQuickPaintedItem` with overloaded mouse events handlers:

```
void Plotter::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "mousePressEvent";
}

void Plotter::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    qDebug() << "mouseMoveEvent";
}

void Plotter::hoverMoveEvent(QHoverEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "hoverMoveEvent";
}
```

I want to add a context menu to this QQuickPaintedItem in QML code, so I have to add MouseArea into this element:

```
Plotter {
    id: plotter
    // ...

    Menu {
        id: contextMenu
        MenuItem { text: "Добавить маркер" }
        MenuItem { text: "Удалить маркер" }
        MenuItem { text: "Удалить все маркеры" }
        MenuItem { text: "Установить шаг" }
   }        

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        propagateComposedEvents: true

        onClicked: {
            if (!mouseScaleButton.checked) {
                contextMenu.popup();
            }
            else
                mouse.accepted = false;

        }

    }
}
```

But it doesn't catch the QQuickPaintedItem's `mousePressEvent` if I press the right button.

Could you please explain why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

The `MouseArea` should only be `enabled: !mouseScaleButton.checked`.

Also, shouldn't the mouse area be below the menu? This way it blocks both the plotter and the menu.

Also, just because you have set `acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton` doesn't necessarily mean it will pass through left clicks (I haven't tested it tho). You may have to enable both buttons and set `mouse.accepted = false` in case of a left click so it can be propagated down.